# PHP if or if somethingelse

Tags: php

Im trying to throw something together in PHP.  I can't seem to get this simple bit to work.

The result I want is if $x = 4, 5, or 6 the output should be hello x is (the value of $x)

here is the code:

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
if ($x != 4 || $x != 5 || $x != 6)
    {echo "hello ";
    echo "x is $x";}
 ?>
```

In the example above the output is "hello x is 1"

however if I change the first line of the code to $x = 4 the expected output is "hello x is 4" when the output should be blank.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You have two conflicting requirements your first part says that you want to print the value of x if x is 4, 5 or 6.  But your second part says you want the opposite.  Which is it?

Comment: Wow, people are quick in downvoting today... please clarify your question, as @GWW said, you give mixed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the opposite logic. You need

```
if ($x == 4 || $x == 5 || $x == 6)
```

Comment: I see what I did now.  I think the best solution is: if ($x != 4 && $x != 5 && $x != 6)

Comment: @Chris: That is I was proposing, but people down voted my answer so fast... anyway, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

> The result I want is if $x = 4, 5, or 6 the output should be hello x is (the value of $x)

in this case, this:

```
if ($x != 4 || $x != 5 || $x != 6)
```

should be:

```
if ($x == 4 || $x == 5 || $x == 6)
```

or:

```
if (in_array($x, array(4,5,6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$x = 4;
if ($x == 4 || $x == 5 || $x == 6)
{echo "hello ";
echo "x is $x";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is functioning correctly--the condition you've written will always be true.  That is, x is always not 4 OR not 5 OR not 6.

If you want to check equality, write `if ($x==4 || $x==5 || $x==6)`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version I can think of is:

```
if ( in_array($x, array(4,5,6)) ) {
    echo 'hello, x is ' . $x;
}
```

The condition above is matched if `$x` is in the list of the following values: `4`, `5` and `6`.

For more see [`in_array()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

**Why your code failed**

The reason your code did not work as expected was because you have created a condition with alternative (`or` or `||`) that is matched if *any* of the expressions within it are matched.

That means that, because at least one of the expressions (eg. `$x != 4`, but in case of `$x` equal to `1` all of the expressions were matched) was matched, the instruction was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
if ($x == 4 || $x == 5 || $x == 6)
    {echo "hello ";
    echo "x is $x";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic table for OR (||):

T || T == T

T || F == T

F || T == T

F || F == F

Logic table for AND (&&):

T && T == T

T && F == F

F && T == F

F && F == F

So for the case of 1:

1!=4 || 1!=5 || 1!=6

T || T || T == T (therefore echo)

For the case of 4:

4!=4 || 4!=5 || 4!=6

F || T || T == T (therefore echo)